# Mendeley 1.19.3 plug-in does not work after Microsoft Word 16.21 update

Tags: microsoft-word, plugins, mendeley

Today I updated Microsoft Word (for Mac) to the 16.21 version, then I realised that the Mendeley (1.19.3) Word plug-in does not work anymore, i.e. I cannot work with the reference system on a Word's file.

Here the error I get from Mendeley:

[error's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnKRj.png)

I tried to re-install the Mendeley plug-in but I still get the same error.

How can I solve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the second solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mendeley-word-plugin-problem/daf1fa81-778f-4fa3-80d1-17133a71d1a6) has worked for me on macos Mojave.

1. Ignore the initial error message and click on the References tab.
2. This should bring up a second error message about Visual Basic for Applications, click on Debug.
3. On the left-hand menu click MacIpcClient
4. Find and Replace all within the file which opens: replace "libc.dylib" with "/usr/lib/libc.dylib"
5. Save (floppy disk icon in the top left)
6. Restart Word.

Comment: hi, please have a look if you can https://superuser.com/questions/1404812/mendeley-desktop-1-19-3-error-53-on-microsoft-word-16-21-for-mac

Comment: I seem to have the same version of Word, Mendeley and macOS as you and this worked for me. Maybe one of the other solutions at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mendeley-word-plugin-problem/daf1fa81-778f-4fa3-80d1-17133a71d1a6 can help? However, Mendeley are aware of the issue and working on a fix: https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28441/supporthub/mendeley/p/10941/

Comment: Did perhaps this work for you when you were on Mojave macOS 10.14.2 but recently you updated to 10.14.3? Because in response to your question I checked and found I had to reapply the above fix, and last night I updated from 10.14.2 to 10.14.3. So for me it still works, I just had to do it again, as I suspect Word somehow reverted to the default settings during the OS update.

Comment: Thanks I am currently downgrading to High Sierra...

Comment: @1000111000 Link is dead